# Pass value of scope to another scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a controller and want to pass a value of a scope to another.

```
app.controller("ChatController", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $timeout, $firebaseAuth, $window) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();

  $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);

  $scope.sendMessage = function() {

   //var firebaseUser = $scope.firebaseUser;

    $scope.messages.$add({
      text: $scope.newMessageText,
      current_time: new Date().toJSON()
    });
    $scope.newMessageText = null;
  };

  $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.firebaseUser = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      auth.$signInWithPopup('google').then(function(firebaseUser) {
        $scope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser; //access this to the sendMessage scope
        console.log(firebaseUser.user);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error;
      });

  };

});
```

Above me, I have `sendMessage` and `login` `scope`. I want to pass the value of `$scope.firebaseUser` to the `login` `scope`. Is that possible?

Comment: Still not got what are you exactly looking for after reviewed your code.

Comment: @Jigar7521 updated the code, you can see a new comment in the sendMessage scope. That's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: ok now it's pretty understandable

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you mixed up Javascript lexical scoping and Angular scopes. In Angular, scope is at the controller level. This means everything within a controller has access to the controller's scope. In turn this means that you can just use the `$scope.firebaseUser` within your `sendMessage` function like so:

```
$scope.sendMessage = function() {

   var firebaseUser = $scope.firebaseUser;

    $scope.messages.$add({
      text: $scope.newMessageText,
      current_time: new Date().toJSON()
    });
    $scope.newMessageText = null;
  };
```

Have you tried this? Did you run into any issues?

Please see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for more details

Comment: Oh. It worked. I'm actually thinking of passing to another controller lol

Answer (score 0):

I have made some edits inside it, please experiment it and let me know, i am waiting. I have used $rootScope for this scenario which is present as a global variable in angular.

> Note : I am writing this code by predict that your existing code is
>   correct totally.

app.controller("ChatController", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $timeout, $firebaseAuth, $window, $rootScope) {
          var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");
          var auth = $firebaseAuth();
          $rootScope.firebaseUser = null;
          $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);

```
      $scope.sendMessage = function() {

       var firebaseUser = $rootScope.firebaseUser;


        $scope.messages.$add({
          text: $scope.newMessageText,
          current_time: new Date().toJSON()
        });
        $scope.newMessageText = null;
      };

      $scope.login = function() {
          $scope.firebaseUser = null;
          $scope.error = null;

          auth.$signInWithPopup('google').then(function(firebaseUser) {
            $scope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser; //access this to the sendMessage scope
          $rootScope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser.user;
            console.log(firebaseUser.user);
          }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
          });

      };

    });
```